# Syntax errors ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nvidia

There are many solutions to this problem online. I appreciate your help.

But, this thread is about how the answered are posted. I am not new to computers but, I am new to Ubuntu and terminals. Most answers I have found list several commands in one continuous line. I can't tell where one command ends and another begins. So I am getting syntax errors.

I simply request that you experts list the commands in a way that newbies like myself can easily input, step by step.

The problem I'm having is

> Blockquote  The following packages have unmet dependencies:libnvidia-ifr1-390: Depends: libnvidia-gl-390 but it is not installed

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you please include the command/link to the answer which you're trying and getting syntax error?

Comment: The line you provide is not a command, but the (incomplete) output of an application. Please take the [tour] first, and read [ask], to learn how you can improve your question. Then tell the whole story, instead of depending on our crystal balls.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt-get --fix-missing
sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-390 libnvidia-ifr1-390
```

If you want to break up a command so that it fits on more than one line, use a backslash `\` as the last character on the line. Bash will print the continuation prompt, usually a >, to indicate that this is a continuation of the previous line.

<sup>**Source:** [Linux Shell Scripting with Bash](https://www.informit.com/store/linux-shell-scripting-with-bash-9780672326424?w_ptgrevartcl)</sup>